# Find a unit vector $q_3$ such that $Q=[q_1 q_2 q_3]$ is a $3\times3$ orthogonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $S= span\ \{x_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1\\ 0\end{bmatrix},\ x_2=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\}$

Using the Gram-Schmidt method, I've found an orthogonal basis $\{u_1, u_2\}$ of $S$
$u_1=x_1$

$u_2=\begin{bmatrix}1/2 \\-1/2\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

and an orthonormal basis $\{q_1, q_2\}$ of $S$

$q_1=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2}/2 \\\sqrt{2}/2\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

$q_2=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{6}/6 \\ -\sqrt{6}/6\\ \sqrt{6}/3\end{bmatrix}$

Now, find a unit vector $q_3$ such that $Q=[q_1 q_2 q_3]$ is a $3\times3$ orthogonal matrix.

I've usually shown my work or my attempt at a solution, but here I have no idea how to find $q_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $Q$ to be orthogonal, we require $q_1 \cdot q_3=0$, $q_2 \cdot q_3=0$, and $|q_3|=1$. Write $q_3 = (a,b,c)^T$, then solve the above system of equations about $a,b,c$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Even easier here. Use the cross product!

Comment: @TedShifrin that's how I solved it actually

Comment: @RomanArefov Great!